# How to pass release_id into the query

Tags: python, sql

Below is my code so far. How to pass release_id into the query?

```
import snowflake.connector
import sys 

cur = con.cursor()

try:
    cur.execute("select release_id, release_codes:transfer_date from food.fruit.apple order by release_id limit 100")
    release_rec=cur.fetchall()
   
    for row in release_rec:  
        #table2       
        cur.execute("SELECT count(*) from  from food.veggie.celery where release_id =row")
        one_row = cur.fetchone()
        print("count for viewing:",one_row[0])
        #table3
        cur.execute("SELECT count(*) from  from food.veggie.cucumber where release_id =row")
        one_row = cur.fetchone()
        print("count for ad_exposure:",one_row[0])
finally:
    cur.close()
cur.close()
```

Comment: Which database adapter?

Comment: And is there any reason why you have been undoing my changes after I formatted your code?

Comment: @KlausD. snowflake. import snowflake & import sys

Comment: @KlausD. I'm sorry, my bad. Wanted to make things clearer by adding to it but apparently not. Sorry, not sure how this works!

Comment: may be put this for clause in a function with release id as argument and the call it as many time as you want.

Answer (score 0):

This should works:

```
cur.execute("SELECT count(*) from food.veggie.celery where release_id = %s", % row["release_id"])
```